# Unable to identify "Authentication Required" Dialog

Tags: javascript, qtp

I'm using QTP 12.02 and chrome v43. How do I make QTP identify the fields inside the dialog box? Object spy only identifies the object behind the dialog box.

[image]

Comment: Hi there, to me your question is more suited over at Server Fault http://serverfault.com Consider posting the question there instead.

Comment: @Henkealg there are zero QTP questions on serverfault and over a thousand on stackoverflow, what makes you think this question belongs there?

Comment: @Motti I mixed up tags and services when writing that comment. My bad, sry. ysj hope you get good answers to your question, and never mind my comment.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know Chrome's authentication dialog is not supported by UFT/QTP, you can however use Insight ([image based](http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/The-Future-of-Testing-Blog/A-guide-to-Image-Based-Testing-with-HP-UFT-s-Insight/ba-p/6355855) testing) in order to pass this dialog.